# flutter model with both .obs and hive fields

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive, flutter-getx

I'm kinda new to flutter.
I am writing an application with Getx and Hive packages.

I would like to make my model observable by making each field reactive. I prefer this approach rather than making the entire class observable in the controller; by doing that it's the model itself that raises the changes and this seems to me more similar to a standard mvvm approach (you can correct me if I am wrong).

I would like also to mark my model fields with @HiveField.

Now, the problem is that I cannot mark Rx fields and I am forced to write two different fields, the Rx one and the Hive one.
Something like that:

```
  @HiveField(1)
  int _fieldDb;

  RxInt fieldRx;

  GbTrait(int value) :
    _fieldDb = value,
    fieldRx = value.obs;
```

By doing that I need to update the two values all the time...Is there a better way?
Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you can listen over the `Rx<T>` like you would do using `Stream`s, so everytime you set a value to that `Rx<T>` another method will execute to update the field also in `Hive`:

```
// ...
Rx<int> RxField  = 0.obs.
RxField.listen((newValue) {
 updateHiveField(newValue);
});

void updateHiveField(int newValue) {
 Hive.box("yourBoxName").putAt(indexOfField, newValue);
}
```

now every time you set a value like this:

```
RxField.value = 10;
```

the `updateHiveField` method automatically will execute updating the `Hive` field.